# How do we describe the relationship of balloon size and related lift?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, air, buoyancy

We know that hydrogen and helium are lighter that air.
Therefore it is certain that they would create a lifting force when enclosed in a balloon.
How do we describe the relationship of balloon size and related lift?

Answer (score 2):

The force is given by [Archimedes' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy#Archimedes.27_principle). For a balloon of mass $m$ containing a volume $V$ of some gas of density $rho_g$, immersed in air of density $\rho_a$, the net upward force is
$$F=-mg+V(\rho_a-\rho_g)g.$$

Some show of an attempt to research the question before posting it here would be quite welcome, though.